# Why can't I see print statements in my RPM spec file?

Tags: centos, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

In my RPM spec file I have the following lines:

```
%pre

echo "This is a test"
```

When I run the "rpmbuild" on my spec file, it builds everything correctly, but I never see the statement "This is a test" ever get printed.

I tried to move the echo statement to the %post section like:

```
%post

echo "This is a test"
```

but still not print statement (even though everything else properly builds).

What can't I see the print statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%pre` and `%post` scriptlets are run at install time, not at build time. You will not see these statements echo'ed out during the `rpmbuild`, you will see them when you install the package with `rpm -i`.